# SQL Server query to make a debit/credit specify computed columns in a table

Tags: sql-server, database

I'm writing a program that have some values and I want to make a specify computed columns in a table and put there the credit/debit columns.

I would want something like that:

```
alter table Dados add [debit/credit] as   [Dollar] > 0   'Credit' else 'Debit'
```

I'm doing something wrong cause this query doesn't work but I know if is written right, it works...

I want to my program to be able to create a column where it writes whether it's "credit" whether is "debit"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You where almost there, just some syntax errors.
you can make a calculated column like this

```
alter table Dados 
add [debit/credit] as case when [Dollar] > 0 then 'Credit' else 'Debit' end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a default to the table that executes a function call.

```
alter table [tablename]
add constraint 
[constraintname]
default([functionname]())
for [tablename]
```